# How to name a date that is half a year after the date of an important or special event?

Tags: word-choice

An anniversary is

> a date that is an exact number of years after the date of an important
>   or special event

I'm wondering if there are some words indicating a date that is **half a year, a fortnight or even a month** after the date of an important or special event.

Comment: Although not strictly an answer to your question, the term "half birthday" is common in the USA. It means six months after your birthday. Its usage is common in grade school, so that classes can celebrate the birthdays of children whose birthday falls during the summer vacation.

Answer (score 6):

Given:

> **semi-**, *prefix*: half of or occurring halfway through (a specified period of time) [MW]

A **semi-anniversary** (or *semianniversary*) would be a six-month anniversary.

(**Edit**: The term *di-anniversary* shows up in searches; the only problem is, **di-** means "twice : twofold : double" **not** "half.")

Some [Googling](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=287486) turns up **mensiversary** (from Latin *mensis* for month) as a term for a *one-month* anniversary.

If you tortured Latin sufficiently, you could probably formulate a term for a *fortnight anniversary*; but then the language police would get you.

Answer (score 1):

There had been some attempts in trying to promote the use of certain neologisms, but none of them apparently really caught on. The safest way of referring to such dates is by using the simpler term anniversary preceded by the period.

I wouldn't personally use any other alternative. Imagine that if they can't agree on a basic period like a month, what is left for fortnights or weeks or any other less common arbitrary period of time.

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anniversary):

> Definition of ANNIVERSARY
>   1 : the annual recurrence of a date
>   marking a notable event;
>   broadly : a date that follows such an event
>   by a specified period of time measured in units other than years

Hope it helps.

Comment: I use "six-month anniversary" and similar terms. Strictly speaking, you're not supposed to do that because "anniversary" comes from the Latin "annus" which means "year", but communication is achieved nevertheless. Nobody has ever asked me to clarify the term "two-month anniversary" for example.

Comment: '*catched on*' sounds new to me?

Comment: http://www.wordreference.com/definition/catch
catch on informal
1 (of a practice or fashion) become popular.

Comment: @tchrist You are right. However I think it's worth mentioning that *catched* used to be the simple past of *to catch* up to some time where its use started to decline in favor of *caught*. Nonetheless, the past tense of the phrasal *to catch on* was never *catched on* but *caught on*; so ... +1 and my apologies.   Wiktionary: catched (obsolete or nonstandard) Simple past tense and past participle of catch. Synonyms: caught

Answer (score -1):

The word you are looking for is Di-anniversary (**Dianniversary**).

"They got together on christmas, so their dianniversary would be june 25th".

Refer this link http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Dianniversary&defid=4049001

and half year is referred to as **"Biannual"**.

Comment: Urban Dictionary is not a reliable source for most things.

Comment: but that is the only word available for half a year celebration as far as i know. its not just on Urban dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Apoorva. Does this word mean two celebrations a year or exactly half a year celebration? I think this two meanings slightly differ.

Comment: It means celebration of exactly half an anniversary. And u r right, two celebrations a year means totally different from this.. 2 Dianniversaries=1 Anniversary.

Comment: Interestingly, the hashtag #dianniversary seems to have taken on a new meaning: the anniversary of a diabetes diagnosis. I found several sites defining "dianniversary" to mean six-month anniversary, but I didn't find any examples of the word in actual usage online.